# Is there a way to get usable data out of a filled PDF with blanks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm hoping  to extract some data from fillable PDFs. The end goal is to put certain things from the form into an excel file. Exporting the data to xls via acrobat does not produce useful data. Since fields in the PDF can (and in some cases must) be left blank, the amount and location in the sheet of the data exported varies making it impossible to process

Is there a way I can get a row or column for every option on the form, even blanks for fields left blank? My organization doesn't have the budget to buy software past Acrobat (we're a non-profit). I also can't use anything that involves uploading the PDFs because they contain participant data

Comment: How are you exporting the fields from acrobat? Are you following this procedure https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/collecting-pdf-form-data.html ? If so, and the blanks are still an issue, perhaps give PDFxchange viewer a try (https://www.tracker-software.com/knowledgebase/261-How-do-I-export-data-from-forms-in-PDF-XChange-Viewer-and-PDF-XChange-Editor). I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but its a great pdf viewer and free versions are available. Lastly consider changing your data sourcing from PDF to google forms. Your data is automatically captured in a google spreadsheet.

Comment: @Mobus I was exporting the data via this method https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Can-I-import-data-fillable-PDF-Form-Excel-spreadsheet-q239812.aspx
I'm not following the procedure you mention because it is not possible for me to "submit" the forms (a necessary step in that procedure) I don't entirely understand the "submit" process for forms, but it understand it involves processing the forms via scripts which is significantly beyond the technical know-how of the place I work

Comment: Unfortunately Google Forms is not an option because were not able to upload confidential participant data to the internet (or at least not something like google forms)

I will look into PDFxchange. Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Does the "merge to spreadsheet" option provide you with a csv file or an excel file? If csv, can you open that csv file in notepad and post a screenshot of a demo file (no private data). It may be that the blanks are there and distinguishable via hidden/tab/comma characters but the way Excel interprets the csv ignores it. This could be corrected either by csv import settings, localisation/regional settings on the computer or even using a search and replace function in a text editor before importing.

Comment: Side note: google forms is protected and encrypted just like gmail or many other online services and does not mean private data is publically accessible just because its stored online. The empty form typically does not contain sensitive info and can be easily shared as a link to users. Alternatively you can share to specific users that also require a log in. Responses are saved to a spreadsheet which is only accessible by authorised log in and thus not public. In many ways the info is more secure, as laptops and hard drives can be stolen and unencrypted data easily accessed.

Comment: If you have Excel 365: Try open the pdf via Powerquery (google for powerquery pdf - you will find a lot of tutorials). Depending on the structure of the pdf this might be a solution.

Comment: @MOBUS I exported it as a CSV and indeed the blanks were there. The CSV imported into excel did properly import the blanks. Sadly doing this with every single file is not an option and I think we're just going to abandon the project. It would have been nice if Acrobat, software my company PAID for, had worked properly but we work with what we have

Comment: @Emily its unfortunate that you feel you must abandon. Just clarify one thing for me, when you use the feature in Acrobat "More Form Options>Merge Data Files into Spreadsheets" and select multiple PDF files and export, everything is exported into a single file right? What is the file format of this single fine, csv or xlsx?